# Export files from database to zip file

Tags: php, zip

I have file names stored in a MySQL database and the files are all pdfs stored in a folder on my server. A user submits a form that POSTs an ID number that is then used in a query that pulls all the filenames. I then need to have them added to a zip file that automatically downloads. The files are in a folder called, "addendums". Below is the code that I have so far. The file is created but, it is empty and says that the file type is not supported. Any help is appreciated. I am using PHP as the code. Also, the query could pull one file or it could even pull 100 files.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) || isset($_POST["submit_x"])) {
$exhibitee_export = new WA_MySQLi_RS("exhibitee_export",$sdpc_i,0);
$exhibitee_export->setQuery("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(signed_addendum_file SEPARATOR ',') AS thesigned_addendum_file FROM (select * from mspa.data where (statusID = 1 or statusID = 15) and softwareID = 918) t1 left join (select * from mspa.addendums_data) t2 on (t2.dataID = t1.dataID) where signed_addendum_file is not NULL");
$exhibitee_export->bindParam("i", "".$_POST['softwareID']  ."", "-1"); //colname
$exhibitee_export->execute();
 $files = $exhibitee_export->getColumnVal("thesigned_addendum_file");
 
$zipname = "export_" . date('Y.m.d H.i.s') . ".zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach (explode(",", $files) as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

///Then download the zipped file.
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
}
?>
```

Comment: After googling a bit it seems you're using [WebAssist software for Adobe Dreamweaver](http://www.webassist.com/dreamweaver-extensions/data-bridge/), is that right? This is something out of the ordinary that should be mentioned in your question. Secondly, what does `$files` look like, before you try to ZIP it?

Comment: Yes, I do use Webassist software but, I am not married to it if there is an easier way.  So, $files would be the pdf files that are listed and separated by commas. I wasn't sure where to write that they are stored in the addendums folder.

Comment: Have you actually checked the content of `$files`? In case you have proven to yourself that they are: _"the pdf files that are listed and separated by commas"_, and by that you mean **a single string** containing comma separated file names, you would need to replace `foreach ($files as $file)` by `foreach (explode(",", $files) as $file)`.

Comment: Ok. I have confirmed what $files is. Here is an example: Quizzezz Signed Ex E.pdf,Quizizz_NHExhibitEMascoma.pdf,Quizizz_NHExhibitEMerrimackValley.pdf,Quizizz_NHExhibitE.pdf,Quizizz_NHExhibitETimberlane.pdf. Where do I tell it to grab the files from the addendums folder?

Comment: Prepend the folder path to `$file` before calling `addFile($file)`.

Comment: Like this: $files = "addendums/".$exhibitee_export->getColumnVal("thesigned_addendum_file")."";